# How to delete the redis keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am able to delete all the redis keys using **FLUSHALL** command. But how do I achieve the same result using a script in nodejs.
Any help in this direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got as far as establishing a connection with redis?  Where are you actually stuck with this?

Answer (score 4):

First, install the [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) client

```
npm install redis --save
```

Then you need to create a connection:

```
import * as redis from 'redis'
const client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_HOST);
```

After that you can delete specific key with the following:

```
client.del('myKey');
```

If you want to delete **all** key-value pairs, use `.flushall()`

```
client.flushall((err, success) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
  console.log(success); // will be true if successfull
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the command this way, worked for me: `client.sendCommand(["FLUSHALL"]);`